# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "DOMDocument"

Tags: php-8

Looking for some help with this error.  I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on an EC2.  I have PHP 8.0 installed with DOM and XML modules installed and loaded.  phpinfo() shows the modules loaded but I'm still getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "DOMDocument".  I have restarted apache.

Comment: Where? Does it happen for any script or just for some specific code?

Comment: I have a php file with just the following code and nothing else

$xml_request = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

Answer (score 0):

I just rebooted the EC2 instance and tested the page again and now it's working.